# How can I shield implementation level classes, traits and objects from Scala public APIs?

Tags: scala, visibility

I'd like to reduce implementation level details from leaking out into my Scala public APIs, and there are so many knobs available for tuning visibility  that my head is spinning from trying to figure out:

> What is the best way to shield implementation level classes, traits
>   and objects from Scala public APIs ?

The best thing I can come up with is to do this:

```
package restaurant {
  trait Service {
    acceptOrder(dish: String, quantity: Int)
  }

  package impl {
    private class ServiceImpl {   // mark this & everything else in package as private
      acceptOrder(dish: String, quantity: Int) = println("order accepted")
    }

    private class ServiceHelper { // mark this & everything else in package as private
      def helpDoStuff() = ???
    }
  }
}
```

But note that I have to mark everything in the impl package with 'private', 
which gets very tedious (and easy to forget) as the number of things in the package increases. It would be great if Scala had an option to declare a > package <  to be private, or at least set the default visibility of all things in a package to be private to that package.  But that does not seem to exist.

I'm sure there are best practice patterns for doing this... Please let me know if you are aware of one.

Update:  I did read about package objects in the [Programming Scala](https://books.google.com/books?id=3XqrBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT117&lpg=PT117&dq=package%20objects%20scala%20public%20API&source=bl&ots=uoZFXGcrkC&sig=QwIOnhfBtF8l1eJJyVBOyN8qQMo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBWoVChMIj6Hg0_HmxwIVFSmICh1H-QND#v=onepage&q=package%20objects%20scala%20public%20API&f=false) book.  And that seems like a nice way to centralize everything in one's public API.  But package objects don't seem to provide a convenient way of hiding visibility of all the objects that are NOT in the package object.

Side note for IDEA users: 
One issue with my nested approach is that it seems to mess up auto-indentation in IDEA. A separate question for me is to find out a work-around for that. I filed a bug with Intellij (if any of you are facing this issue and want to vote on it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144872)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question!

What about using a private object? Of course this will only work if you can
implement your service in a single file. Otherwise I think the impl namespace approach is the best you can do.

```
package restaurant

sealed trait Service {
  def acceptOrder(dish: String, quantity: Int): Unit
}

object Service {
  def create: Service = new Impl.ServiceImpl()

  private object Impl {
    class ServiceImpl extends Service {
      def acceptOrder(dish: String, quantity: Int) = println("order accepted")
    }

    class ServiceHelper {
      def helpDoStuff() = ???
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to break it into separate files, just use multiple `private[restaurant]` objects.

Comment: hmmm.. interesting. Thank you, Rüdiger.  I notice you used 'sealed' for the trait. I am guessing that if I tried to break the implementation out into several files i wouldn't be able to use 'sealed' do you agree ?   Also.. sealed would seem to interfere with my ability to create mock implementations of Service in separate files.  So, I would tend to want to avoid 'sealed'.. But even without sealed, this seems to me to be a good solution.     Please let me know if you think the solution would suffer without sealed. And thanks again for the tip.

Comment: @ChrisBedford I use sealed because I often use traits just as a way to separate interface and implementation. But of course you can omit it if you want to implement it in multiple places. (However, I have found that I rely on inheritance less and less the more I use FP concepts such as typeclasses)

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is just

```
package restaurant {
  trait Service {
    acceptOrder(dish: String, quantity: Int)
  }

  private[restaurant] class ServiceImpl {
    acceptOrder(dish: String, quantity: Int) = println("order accepted")
  }

  private[restaurant] class ServiceHelper {
    def helpDoStuff() = ???
  }
}
```

But yes, this is quite tedious to repeat.